# Como cambiar la Bola que rebota al simbolo '*'

Tags: python

Hola tengo este codigo que es una pelota rebotando, y lo que quiero es cambiar la forma de esa pelota por el simbolo '*' pero no se como hacerlo, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a cambiar, Gracias!

```
    from tkinter import * 

raiz = Tk()
raiz.title("PING PONG") 
raiz.geometry("800x250") 

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 250
canvas = Canvas(raiz, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

ball = canvas.create_oval(5, 5, 25, 25, fill='black')

xspeed = yspeed = 5

def moveBall():

    global xspeed, yspeed

    canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)

    (leftPos, topPos, rightPos, bottomPos) = canvas.coords(ball)

    if leftPos <= 0 or rightPos >= WIDTH:
        xspeed = -xspeed
    if topPos <= 0 or bottomPos >= HEIGHT:
        yspeed = -yspeed

    canvas.after(30, moveBall)

canvas.after(30, moveBall)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Asi me sale
[image]

Comment: Esta bien lograda la animación.

Comment: Si lo se pero quiero es cambiar la forma de esa pelota por el simbolo '*'

Answer (score 4):

En lugar de usar `create_oval` usa `create_text`:

```
ball = canvas.create_text(5, 5, anchor="nw", text="*", font=("Arial", "32"))
```

- Los primeros dos argumentos son en que coordenadas xy se crea el texto.
- Anchor determina que punto del objeto del canvas será ubicado en esas coordenadas. Por ejemplo `anchor="center"` significa que el centro del objeto será ubicado en esas coordenadas. `anchor="nw"` significa que se ubicará la esquina noroeste allí. Más información en https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/anchors.html
- Puedes determinar el tamaño del `*` usando el argumento font y proporcionando una fuente de tamaño especifico.

Más información sobre este método aquí: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_text.html

Por la forma en la que está creado el text, el método coords del canvas devolverá las coordenadas xy en lugar de las 4 coordenadas del ovalo.
Para solucionar esto recomiendo usar el comando bbox, que devuelve las coordenadas del rectangulo donde está contenido el item.

```
(leftPos, topPos, rightPos, bottomPos) = canvas.bbox(ball)
```

Tu código completo quedaría así:

```
from tkinter import * 

raiz = Tk()
raiz.title("PING PONG") 
raiz.geometry("800x250") 

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 250
canvas = Canvas(raiz, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

#ball = canvas.create_oval(5, 5, 25, 25, fill='black')
ball = canvas.create_text(5, 5, anchor="nw", text="*", font=("Arial", "32"))

xspeed = yspeed = 5

def moveBall():

    global xspeed, yspeed

    canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)

    #(leftPos, topPos, rightPos, bottomPos) = canvas.coords(ball)
    (leftPos, topPos, rightPos, bottomPos) = canvas.bbox(ball)

    if leftPos <= 0 or rightPos >= WIDTH:
        xspeed = -xspeed
    if topPos <= 0 or bottomPos >= HEIGHT:
        yspeed = -yspeed

    canvas.after(30, moveBall)

canvas.after(30, moveBall)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow quedo perfecto, muchas gracias amigo!